# Can For loop be used with multiple conditions?

Tags: conditional

I am wondering if `For` could be used with multiple conditions (tests). For the simple example `For[i = 0, i < 4; i > 0, i++, Print[i]]` which prints 0, 1, 2, 3, is it possible to add another condition `EvenQ[i]` such that it only prints 0 and 2?

I tried `For[i = 0, i < 4 && EvenQ[i], i++, Print[i]]` which seems natural but does not work. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Your test `i<4 && EvenQ[i]` is a stopping condition, so the `For` loop *stops* after $i=0$.

Comment: `a;b` always evaluates to `b`.  Thus writing `i < 4; i > 0` is the same as writing `i > 0`.  Your first example doesn't really make sense.   The second prints `0` because when `i==1`, `EvenQ[i]` evaluates to `False`, thus the loop stops.

Comment: why not use `i += 2` for the increment?

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you. Sorry in the first example I meant without `;i>0`. But your pointing that out does answer another question of mine as if `i < 4; i > 0` is actually two simultaneous conditions. I will take your comment as the answer.